# Entity Framework 7 Migrations not automatically creating database in SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created a new ASP.NET 5 web app and added a few model classes then added them to the ApplicationDbContext.

I opened command-line and browsed to my project's root directory and typed:

```
dnx ef migrations add InitialDatabase
```

It says created successfully, but is not auto-generating the database in SQL SERVER. Here is my connection string:

```
Server=BLAKE-XY6572;Database=TestDatabase;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

There are no errors and the Migrations/InitialDatabase.cs file is created which is why I am confused.

Comment: Now we need more information - at least entities and DbContext source code.

Comment: You need to run `dnx ef database Update` after that command which will create the db

Comment: Yeah I figured out my problem. A tutorial I was doing always made me put EnsureDatabaseCreated in the constructor of my dbContext and I never noticed that when this is here you do not have to call dnx ef database update. If it isn't there then you do.